# Why in Hilbert's Hotel paradox can you not simply put the new guests at room $n+1$?

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, elementary-number-theory, infinity

I understand how in the infinite hotel 'paradox' moving every person in room $n$ to room $n+1$, and then putting the new quests in room $1$, generates a new space in the countable, but infinite, set.

What I don't understand is why the new guests can't be moved straight to $n+1$, where $n$ is the final room. Or have the current guests at $n$ move to $n+1$ and the new guests move to $n$.

Is it due to $n$ being inaccessible directly, so that you need to build to it iteratively? Is it a genuine requirement?

If it is, then why not build a function $f$ such that:

$$f : X \to X', f(n) = \left\{ \begin{array} {ll} n, \ \text{if room} \ n \ne 0 \\ \text{new family, otherwise} \end{array} \right.$$ (terminating after the second condition is met, and iterating over $X$ in order beforehand)?

Comment: The hotel is supposed to be infinite.

Comment: If there are infinitely many rooms, then which room is room $n$?  If the entire hotel is full, then how is room $n+1$ empty?

Comment: If we put the guest into Room $n$ say, and move the current occupant to $n+1$, then we will have to put the current occupant of $n+1$ somewhere, say $n+2$, and then the occupant of $n+2$ will have to be moved, and so on. Remember, the hotel has infinitely many rooms, Room 1, Room 2, Room 3, and so on, and they are all occupied.

Comment: Oh gosh. It really is that simple isn't it.
There's no way to see that any family will reach n+1, only the guarantee that each of them will still have a room. Is that correct?

Comment: @liqiudilk you still have to clarify what $n$ is supposed to be here.  There is certainly no integer value of $n$ that makes sense here.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, you're right. As the set is countable and infinite n denotes an integer counter over the set which has no largest number. What I should have said was that moving people from n to n+1 will never terminate (i.e., it will never 'reach' the cardinality of the set), but at the same time no guest will ever be without a room. Is that correct understanding and language?

Comment: There is no final room, but you could start from room n+1 instead of room 1. I.e. Leave everybody in the first n rooms where they are and move n+1 to n+2 etc so creating a vacancy in n+1.

Comment: The paradox of Hilbert's Hotel is often used to develop essential properties of infinite sets, especially that of proper subsets having the same "size" as the whole set. (All guests can be moved to a proper subset of all the rooms in Hilbert's infinite hotel.) See my blog posting, "Infinity: The Story So Far." As a more intuitive, paradox-free alternative to Hilbert's Hotel, I start by nailing down the notion of a finite village -- first informally, then formally. Then infinite is just the negation of finite. See http://www.dcproof.wordpress.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're assuming that Hilbert's hotel has an empty "$(n+1)$th" room.  Note, however, that the entire hotel is full.  So, there are **no empty rooms**.

Comment: Answered also in discussion in the comment section above.